# Customize Internal Server Error apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have recently moved my site from, say, www.example.com/coreTasks, to coreTasks.example.com, and I'd like to redirect visitors who have been given the link to the old site, to the new site.

I've been getting complaint about an error message "Internal Server Error 500" or 404 error.

What I'm trying to do is to customize this error so that it will inform them of the fact that the site has been moved, and will automatically redirect them to the right site after 5 seconds. I have written a small html code and named it 500.html and 404.html.

In my .htaccess file, I have:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 500 /custom_template/500.html
ErrorDocument 404 /custom_template/404.html

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

Below is what I have got in both 404.html and 500.html

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=https://coreTasks.example.com/">
```

But it appears that it doesn't load up either 500.html or 404.html.

Just wonder if I have missed out on anything here.

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you try moving the `ErrorDocument` declarations outside the `IfModule` block? Do you have `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes, I tried that before - having the ErrorDocument after </IfModule>. This didn't work, which is why I moved it inside the module. And yes, I think I have mod_rewrite enabled because in my httpd.conf, there is no # next to LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so. Thank you